# load yaml with code

Tags: rospy, rosparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to load a .yaml file in python directly to the parameter server? I want to do something like "rosparam load", but programmatically, as a callback for an event in a GUI.

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/169866/load-yaml-with-code/) by [crpizarr](https://answers.ros.org/users/9346/crpizarr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2014-05-26

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2015-05-26**:
This is duplicate of http://answers.ros.org/question/58819/programatically-load-yaml-config-file-to-the-parameter-server/, there is an answer there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should be able to load a YAML file into a python data structure using the [pyyaml module](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation).

You can then use [`rospy.set_param('/prefix', data)`](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Parameter%20Server#Setting_parameters) to push the entire contents of your data structure to a prefix on the parameter server.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [crpizarr](https://answers.ros.org/users/9346/crpizarr/) on 2014-05-26**:
It's not the same as doing "rosparam load" . I've tried what you propose, but it does not make the namespace structure as "rosparam load" does. I mean, with "rosparam load file.yaml" I load all the namespaces in the file, that is, the data I can access is just the leaves of the structure. and all the internal nodes in the file are loaded as namespaces. With rospy.set_param, I just set the "/prefix" with a dictionary, so I can't access the data with rospy.get_param("/prefix/namespace1/namespace2").

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-05-26**:
That's a bit surprising. What sort of structure/namespaces do you get on the parameter server after uploading a dict with set_param? It might be worth adding what you've tried to your question, particularly a small piece of python and the resulting `rosparam list /prefix` and `rosparam get /prefix`